# GitHub API - List of Languages

Tags: github, github-api

Is there an endpoint in the GitHub API that will provide me with a list of ALL the languages on GitHub? I'm looking for similar results to the Languages drop-down in the "Trending" section on the github.com website.

Answer (score 6):

Not from GitHub API directly.

The [OP AgileAce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3247591/agileace) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423956/github-api-list-of-langauges/21424163?noredirect=1#comment32321604_21424163):

> I've discovered that there is a [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist) maintained by GitHub.
>   In this repo, there is a YAML file ([**`lib/linguist/languages.yml`**](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml)) containing all the languages, and related info.
>   I'm just going to write a script that will parse this file.

I mentioned the linguist library in "[How does github figure out a project's language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318688/6309)".

---

You can also get that data from various GitHub statistic sites, like [www.githubarchive.org](http://www.githubarchive.org/):

See "[Top Github Languages for 2013 (so far)](http://adambard.com/blog/top-github-languages-for-2013-so-far/)", by ADAM BARD:

> I just discovered the [Github Archive](http://www.githubarchive.org/), a dataset of Github events queryable using [Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/). What fun! So I decided to count how many repositories have been created this year by language.

```
SELECT repository_language, count(repository_language) AS repos_by_lang
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE repository_fork == "false"
AND type == "CreateEvent"
AND PARSE_UTC_USEC(repository_created_at) >= PARSE_UTC_USEC('2013-01-01 00:00:00')
AND PARSE_UTC_USEC(repository_created_at) < PARSE_UTC_USEC('2013-08-30 00:00:00')
GROUP BY repository_language
ORDER BY repos_by_lang DESC
LIMIT 100
```

[coderstats.net](http://coderstats.net/info/about/) could be a good source too, with its **[language section](http://coderstats.net/languages/)**.

Comment: Thanks, VonC. 

I've discovered that there is a Linguist library maintained by GitHub at https://github.com/github/linguist. In this repo, there is a YAML file containing all the languages, and related info.

I'm just going to write a script that will parse this file.

Comment: @AgileAce sounds great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as a link to that [`lib/linguist/languages.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml) file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a yaml parser to parse all supported languages by github ( their linguistic.yml file )

```
npm i js-yaml
```

```js
import { load } from "js-yaml";
let result = []

const getLangs = () => {
  fetch(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/linguist/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml",
  )
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((yamlString) => load(yamlString))
    .then((data) => {
      for (let key in data) {
        if (data[key].aliases) result = result.concat(data[key].aliases);
      }

    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    
return result
};
```