# Why the field "language" returns null on org.eclipse.egit.github.core API to all repositories?

Tags: java, eclipse, github, egit

I am researching for my master degree studies and when my program, searches the language of repository using `org.eclipse.egit.github.core` API, the service response returns `null` for the field "language" to all repositories.

API version: 3.3.X RC and 3.4.0 RC (JAVA)

Anyone had the same experience or know help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [org.eclipse.egit.github.core.service.RepositoryService getLanguages()](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/RepositoryService.java#L774-L793) function, and it should work as expected.
See an example at "[org.eclipse.egit.github.core.tests.live.RepositoryTest](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/dc4a6439fa8e8ca2785cdf149b9ac3b757372f75/org.eclipse.egit.github.core.tests/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/tests/live/RepositoryTest.java#L119-L130)"

```
/**
 * Get languages used in a repository
 *
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Test
public void getLanguages() throws IOException {
    RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService(client);
    Map<String, Long> languages = service.getLanguages(new RepositoryId(
            "defunkt", "resque"));
    assertNotNull(languages);
    assertFalse(languages.isEmpty());
    for (Entry<String, Long> language : languages.entrySet()) {
        assertNotNull(language.getKey());
        assertFalse(language.getKey().length() == 0);
        assertTrue(language.getValue() > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to decide which is the primary language for the repository, or there is not a way?

Comment: @TarcisioM. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5318688/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21989630/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21424163/6309, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23602158/6309 have some elements on that.