# GitHub statistics not working

Tags: github

I'm not sure where to ask this, if this is not the place feel free to close the post, but here's whats going on. A mate of mine has his repository on GitHub, but for some reason the language statistics aren't showing. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any ideas? [Here's](https://github.com/Colourity/Fort.js) the repository

Comment: Stack Overflow is not [Github Support](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: Well I wasn't sure if there was a way to enable them, additionally the github tag @JonathonReinhart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [GitHub language detection](https://github.com/github/linguist) is based on linguist (as I described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318688/6309)).

- The list of file extension analyzed is in [`lib/linguist/languages.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml)
- The list of files ignored is in [`lib/linguist/vendor.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/vendor.yml)

In your case, your js/css/json files could be:

- <del>too small to trigger that analysis</del>
- or **too recent** for that analysis to be completed

I suggest to wait another day before raising a ticket to GitHub support.

---

Update a few hours later: I suspect the language stats are only updated once a day, as they now are present on the [OP's GitHub repo](https://github.com/Colourity/Fort.js):

[image: language stats]

This is still the case in 2017, with [pchaigno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6884590/pchaigno)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600032/github-statistics-not-working/23602158#comment78267850_23602158):
([Paul Chaignon](https://twitter.com/pchaigno) is one of the [main contributors on the linguist project](https://github.com/github/linguist/graphs/contributors))

> The language detection job (Linguist) is actually running as a background, low-priority job.
>   So it may take some time to update. Can be a few minutes, or a day.

You can see an example in "[Paths not excluded from Github language statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42544813/6309)", where [Paul suggests a way to debug how linguist applies to your repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654985/6309).

Comment: I sent a ticket and got a response early this morning, it said. _Sorry about that. The language statistics for that repository should be showing up now._ Wonder if they have the ability to disable and enable it.....

Comment: The language detection job (Linguist) is actually running as a background, low-priority job. So it may take some time to update. Can be a few minutes, or a day.

Comment: @pchaigno Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.